# Are the Jupiter-Io Lagrange points stable?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity, jupiter

Lagrange points are solutions to the three-body problem. Moving among Jupiter's Galilean moons seems likely to be at least a six-body problem, so there is no reason to assume the three-body solutions work -- ie, Ganymede is going to have an influence on the stability of any orbit near Io or Europa. But, the moons are all in resonance, so their mutual effects won't be random. Can anybody point me at a discussion of how that works out?

**In response to comments:** I'm just interested if anyone has examined what happens -- if the Lagrange points are metastable but eventually test bodies get punted, how long does that take? or if there are still stable points, do they move from the standard +/- 60º positions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stable"? Do you mean orbits near those locations are stable (e.g.: Trojans) ? Or their existence and approximate locations are constant ?

Comment: @Woody I'll bet the OP would be interested in any work on trajectories that a *closed and periodic for at least a while*. It may be counterproductive to overly specify/constrain answers at this point. They've already made it clear that the traditional 3-body solutions are not likely to apply but because of resonances, interesting solutions based on more bodies may still exist. Those are not going to look like the Lagrange point-associated orbits in 3-body systems.

Comment: I'm just interested if anyone has examined what happens -- if the Lagrange points are metastable but eventually test bodies get punted, how long does that take? or if there are still stable points, do they move from the standard +/- 60º positions?

Answer (score 2):

Relatively speaking the spacing of Galilean bodies seems roughly the same as the rocky bodies in our inner solar system.

[image]

Venus comes fairly close to us yet we don't have much problem putting [SOHO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory) in a halo orbit around the Sun Earth L1 point.

So, in my opinion, yes. But I'm not super sure about that.

The Galilean moon mass/Jupiter mass tends to be a more significant fraction than inner rocky planet/over sun mass. So the planets hug their L1 and L2 points tighter, so to speak:

[image]

This may make the Galilean L1 and L2 points more vulnerable to perturbations from neighbors.

An irrelevant point of interest: I make gas giant moons L1 and L2 points the moon synchronous orbits to build space elevators in the so called [mini solar system](https://hopsblog-hop.blogspot.com/2013/01/mini-solar-systems.html) science fiction setting.

[image]

Comment: You talk about L1 and L2 a lot in this answer, but [when we talk about stable LaGrange points we're almost surely referring to L4 and L5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point#Stability_2), as OP also indicates by talking about "the standard +/- 60º positions"